# Dynamic Pivot tables

Tags: sql-server, dynamic, pivot

I'm trying to execute multiple pivot tables, dynamically, every time with the column values horizontally.

I tried to execute the following query, but it fails for some reason, even though when I print the query and execute it subsequently, everything works just fine.

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = (
SELECT ' SELECT '+ QUOTENAME(c.name)
    + '
      ,[1] AS a
      ,[2] AS b
      ,[3] AS c
FROM 
    (SELECT [ID]
            ,CASE WHEN [c1] < 25 THEN 1
              ELSE CASE WHEN [c1] < 45 THEN 2
              ELSE 3 END END AS cat
            ,' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + '
    FROM [dbo].[table]) p
PIVOT
(
COUNT (ID)
FOR cat IN ([1], [2], [3] )
) AS pvt
ORDER BY [2] desc
'
FROM sys.columns c
    WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.SAMR_respons')
    AND c.name NOT IN ('ID')
    FOR XML PATH('')
)

PRINT(@sql)
EXEC(@sql);
```

Does anyone know what might go wrong?
The error I get is:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near ';'.
```

Comment: you try removing the exec and just printing your dynamic sql statement...? It's not fully dynamic... so that exec command shouldn't work.

Comment: Thx for your quick reply. Can you tell me why the statement is not fully dynamic?

Comment: You are trying to call EXEC on a result set, which is the value of @sql.